# Do Google Analytics 4 Refund Events affect the total revenue, when there is no corresponding transaction?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

After fumbling around for a while I have concluded, that to refund a transaction in Google Analytics 4, it is enough to use the same `transactionId` as the original transaction that is being refunded (plus the value, items, etc., I have managed to successfully refund already).

However, since I am tracking the **refunds server-side** and the **transactions client-side**, there will be a  few refunds that do not correspond to a transaction. How does GA 4 handle those refunds? Are they subtracted from the total revenue, and if yes, is it possible to filter them out?

Comment: The documentation here is lacking a lot in my opinion, I haven't found anything on the value being positive or negative, or what the `transactionId` references. Through some testing and examples I have concluded: `transactionId` same as original order, `value` the positive sum of all refunded items.